# jQuery disregaring dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues with posting values on dynamically created input fields. I have a page with input and giving a user an option to add extra content i.e + button to create extra input fields. Any additional fields that are created are not being submited inside of my post request (jQuery). Only original single field is being posted.

Here is my div:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <div class="input-group-prepend mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text">VLAN ID & NAME</span>
    </div>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="vlan_id" id="vlan_id" placeholder="e.g: 123" requiredmin="1" max="4094" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vlan_name" id="vlan_name" placeholder="e.g: CXX1_LAN01" required />
      <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-circle add_new_vlan_field"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="vlan_info_block"></div>
</div>
```

Dynamic input creation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 5;
    var wrapper = $(".vlan_info_block");
    var add_button = $(".add_new_vlan_field");
    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (x < max_fields) {
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append(
          '<div class="input-group input-group-sm"><div class="input-group-prepend mb-3"><span class="input-group-text">VLAN ID & NAME</span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="vlan_id" id="vlan_id"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="vlan_name" id="vlan_name"><a href="#" class="btn btn-circle delete" role="button"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a></div>'
        );
      } else {
        alert("You Reached the limits of max allowed VLAN(s) - 5");
      }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent("div").remove();
      x--;
    });
  });
```

This is my post:

```
$("#add_job").on("click", function () {
    var pod = document.getElementById("pod").value;
    var vlan_id = document.getElementById("vlan_id").value;
    var vlan_name = document.getElementById("vlan_name").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/testing_tasks",
        data: {
          pod,
          vlan_id,
          vlan_name
        },
        method: "POST",
      })
      .done((res) => {
        getStatus(res.data.task_id);
      })
      .fail((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are creating multiple elements with the same `id`, they have to be unique. Change them to use common `class` attributes instead. To send across data from multiple elements you would be best to create an array of the values, however exactly how your format the request will also affect the server side code, as it looks like right now it's only designed to receive single values.

Comment: Also `wrapper` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to re-jquerify it in `$(wrapper)`, you can just use directly `wrapper.append(...)`

Comment: backed is Flask based using request.form.get["name"] it works with standard POST i.e not using jQuery however, i'm receiving a list of values.